# HttpWebRequest vs RestSharp which one should I use to make Rest call to Azure and Amazon Services

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, httpwebrequest, azure-storage, restsharp

I have to make some Rest call to Azure Storage api as well as some Amazon service. I can see there exists lots of options(HttpWebRequest, WebClient, HttpClient, RestSharp)  that i can use to make REST call.

I have used HttpClient several times before but i don't want to use that because HttpClient  unable to support anything prior to .NET 4.5 .

Now, I have two options HttpWebRequest and RestSharp.

I have seen some code snippet of HttpWebRequest that shows how I can call the Azure service, on the other hand i didn't see anyone using RestSharp to connect to Azure service. RestSharp seems easier and smart. But since i never worked with this before I am bit confused if it can handle everything seamlessly.

Please suggest among these two option which one I should use and why.

Comment: Earlier I thought I will go for HttpWebRequest but  that requires too much code+some of the steps HttpWebRequest required are not straight forward. 

That is why I would like to give a shot to RestSharp. But again since both amazon and azure API services were pretty old, their API exposing technique might need some extra care. I am bit worried if RestSharp could handle those things.

Comment: Comparing these options comes down to opinion unless we have more detail on what you're trying to do. What are your application requirements? Why can't you use the existing client libraries that do all of this for you for Azure and Amazon? What have you tried and what didn't work?